# I have to escape % but all online example does not

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

For some reason in my Visual Studio 2012 when I try to get an server tag using jquery I have to escape the `%` like this and it causes my code to not work.

```
$('#<\%= myInput.ClientID %>').val(content);
```

but all the example that I have seen online does not need to they just do this

```
$('#<%= myInput.ClientID %>').val(content);
```

Is there something specific that I need to do to visual studio first?

**EDIT**
Sorry. I am trying to do is get a value of an element in asp.net using jquery. Let say I have this.

```
<asp:Label ID=" myInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PersonID") %>' />
```

and then inside my script tags I have this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function DoX(){alert( $('#<%= myInput.ClientID %>').val();
```

)};

Comment: You question is confusing. Are you passing the selector dynamically using `<%= .. %>` tag?

Comment: So you're trying to get ASP.NET to load the javascript and substitute myInput's ID where that code is?  Does Visual Studio give you a build error or just underline it like it's an error?  If you get a build error, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: @Vega No I am not passing the selector dynamically. myInput is the Id of the element.

Comment: @Garrison Neely It does not give me a build error just an underline error like as if I am missing a quotes.

Comment: But have you run the code?  Sometimes Visual Studio will squiggly underline stuff that still works.

Comment: @Garrison Neely Yeah I ran it and it says it does not recognize myInput